# choir or chorus in this case?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, difference

If I'm referring to the sound of a group of about twelve people who is at home and singing happy birthday informally, should I use the word "choir" or "chorus"?

As in:

> I heard a **choir/chorus** from the apartment next door singing happy
> birthday.

While these two words do have different meanings in some cases, in others, such as this, they seem to overlap.

Comment: _Choir_ would imply that it was an organised group of singers, which this presumably wasn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with Kate Bunting that "choir" would suggest an organized group. The word "chorus" can also be sued for such a group, but it does not imply such organization as strongly. But I would suggest:

> I heard a group of people from the apartment next door singing "Happy Birthday".

This more clearly indicates an informal gatehring, in my view, which is probably the intent here.